# Lowercase L key does not work in cygwin terminal

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin

This is probably the weirdest software problem I have ever come across.

When I press <kbd>L</kbd> key in cygwin command line I see no reaction whatsoever. All other buttons on the keyboard work perfectly. In ALL other programs (including vi and cmd.exe, as shown on the screencast) <kbd>L</kbd> works.

Does anyone have ideas what could cause this? Reboot, cygwin reinstallations did not help. Reproducible in both cygwin 32 and 64 bit.

I have Windows 8 64bit.

Captured a small video describing the problem (sorry, youtube messed up the quality and the sound, as usual): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjJ9FEwWVBs

Comment: I suggest asking on the cygwin mailing list  http://www.cygwin.com/lists.html  (email a blank message to cygwin-subscribe@cygwin.com ) that should then subscribe you and say how to email the mailing list (probably will be cygwin@cygwin.com or something) can unsubscribe when done. cygwin-unsubscribe@cygwin.com   in case it's high volume.

Comment: out of interest is it mintty.exe or is it from the command prompt running cygwin.bat and is there a difference in whether 'l' is recognised? and can you paste an 'l' in from charmap? just things that may be worth looking into.

Comment: 1) This is cygwin.bat, but there is no difference; 2) I cannot paste this character from anywhere else to command line; 3) RAlt+108 does not work either

Comment: re '2' I guess you mean to cygwin command line cos cmd command line is fine

Comment: so if you copy the text elelelel(8 character to the clipboard) what does it paste? eeee ?

Comment: yes, exactly :) I get eeee and this is very funny

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15126/discussion-between-barlop-and-alex-petrenko).

Comment: Probably your key bindings are messed up (this is as easy as this: `bind -r l`). A very good explanation is given by [Dennis Williamson on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4905835/2037712).

Comment: Thank you very much, Dennis! I had somehow messed up inputrc script. The solution from SO answer works perfectly. You can add an answer and I'll accept it (otherwise I'll do it myself for other people who may need help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be related to corrupted ~/.inputrc file

```
bind '"l":self-insert'
```

this is what solved the issue for me. Also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905593/cannot-type-e-or-p-in-mingw-msys-shells-or-terminals/4905835#4905835) for more details.